# ¿Cómo revertir el último commit a master?

Tags: git

Pasa esto, tengo dos ramas principales: master y desarrollo.

Hasta el momento master tenía un commit (el del inicio del proyecto) y mi rama desarrollo tenía varios commits.

Mi flujo es este: Creo una rama cada que voy a hacer algún cambio y al terminar le hago un merge a desarrollo

```
$ git checkout desarrollo && git merge rama-de-cambio
```

Accidentalmente se realizó el merge a master usando

```
$ git checkout master && git merge rama-de-cambio
```

¿Cúal es la manera de regresar a master a su estado original y poder hacer mi merge a mi rama de desarrollo?

Comment: Gracias, eso me dio una idea de lo que tenía que hacer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que debes de hacer es localizar el commit guardado en la rama-de-cambio antes de hacer el merge y luego

```
git reset --hard <commit-rama-de-cambio>
```

Answer (score 1):

La versión corta:

```
1. Obtener los hash ids de los últimos commits.
2. Retornar al commit deseado.
3. Enviar los cambios al repositorio.
4. Actualizar repositorios.
```

---

Este sería el procedimiento en detalle:

Si por alguna razón necesitamos revertir los archivos de nuestro repositorio de Git a un push anterior, debemos seguir los siguientes pasos.

**1. Obtener hash ids de los últimos commits.**
En necesario Identificar el hash id del commit al que queremos regresar, con el siguiente comando vamos a ver los últimos 10 ids:

```
?$ git log -10 --pretty="%H"
```

30ace57438659c6a715db441ffc6751f385db667
484121a5ed21e8b842ffe61783fde059103185b3
996ee5f0aabd18d14a73e0181780dcc9191337f4
2b0ea751d69c84b909b3011ba5de865125d209b2
944385404a3468fe6665be2d8cf1a71a5c995196
6b832d19e44d298d60c99a382f9e7e282c9c16f2
fad00716beff7b48890f0a96d82780bea685f39e
4339ddc09724d93bac456221a0c369c3d5a62c89
cf9a82f09bb799c2449854ba7d33ddf2cfff3b84
adf47c09992f147ab2b631713cc8dd612f21e83d

**2. Retornar al commit deseado.**
Cunando hayamos identificado el commit al que deseamos regresar nuestro repositorio debemos ejecutar un comando similar al siguiente.

```
?$ git reset --hard 484121a5ed21e8b842ffe61783fde059103185b3
```

HEAD is now at 484121a

**3. Enviar los cambios al repositorio.**
Ahora debemos enviar los cambios al repositorio con el siguiente comando.

```
?git push --force
```

**4. Actualizar repositorios.**
Si tenemos algún clone del provecto en otro lugar, debemos hacer checkout del commit al que deseamos volver ejecutando el siguiente comando.

```
?git checkout 484121a5ed21e8b842ffe61783fde059103185b3
```

Espero les sea de utilidad.

fuente original:

http://www.7sabores.com/blog/como-revertir-un-push-git

Comment: Se ve mucho mejor esta explicación, muchas gracias por editarla.